# axios req failed Error: Request failed with status code 404 at createError (createError.js:16) at settle (settle.js:17) at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad

Tags: javascript, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

my patch request is not working.When I make patch request without **AsyncThunk**, it works fine and doesn't give any error but when using Thunk it fails and giving following error.
Error can be seen here in this image

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I am sending postData(underlined blue) .but I am unable to find why it is showing payload undefined.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
Plus I am passing 2 values as object to "asyncThunk" because it takes only one argument as a payload.Is that is the problem or not!
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

````
export const updatePost=createAsyncThunk(
    'Post/updatePost',
    async({id,updatePost})=>{
      try{
      const {data}=await api.updatePost(id,updatePost);
      console.log(data)
       return data;

      }catch(err){
        console.log('axios patch req failed',err)
      }
    }
)

const postSlice=createSlice({
name:'Post',
initialState:{
posts:[],
status:'failure'
},
extraReducers:{
[updatePost.fulfilled]:(state,action)=>{
  console.log(action.payload)
    state.status='success'
              
    return state.posts.map((post)=>post._id === action.payload._id ?action.payload :post)
  },
  [updatePost.pending]:(state,action)=>{
    state.status='pending'
    console.log('pending due to',action)

  },
  [updatePost.rejected]:(state,action)=>{
    state.status='rejected'
    console.log('updatePost is rejected',action)

  }
}
})```

** here is my patch request function **

```export const updatePost=(id,updatePost)=>axios.patch(`${url}/${id}`,updatePost)```

** dispatching my action **
```dispatch(updatePost({currentId,postData}))```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb37y.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/86a4l.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0CLP.png
````

Answer (score 1):

Upon looking in the error image it is showing that something in the data is being sent as `undefined`
I suggest console.log and check what is sent as undefined and try to resolve that or update the question with some other information as well.
[image]

Comment: export const updatePost=createAsyncThunk(
  'Post/updatePost',
  async({id,updatePost})=>{
    try {
      console.log(id,updatePost)
      const {data}=await api.updatePost(id,updatePost)
      return data
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }------------------------  On console.log(id,updatePost) ,it is showing both as undefined

Comment: It means the values, id and updatePost are undefined try to check the calling function.